# Google Tag Manager uses Sandboxed JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

In the help https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/templates/sandboxed-javascript?hl=en, Google saw material that says that Google Tag Manager uses Sandboxed JavaScript. This is in the templates section. Is Sandboxed JavaScript used only there when developing templates and tags for GTM or in the GTM interface when setting up variables, triggers and tags? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is used only in templates, in custom HTML tags and in custom Javascript variables you can use all JS features. This creates security risks (e.g. if you load third party assets with malicious payloads), which is why Google has created custom templates. As the template apis start to cover more and more ground, you really shouldn't use custom script anymore and build custom templates instead.

Comment: It turns out that Google Tag Manager uses full JavaScript. But still, some functions in it do not work, for example, declaring variables through let / const?

Comment: I don't think GTM supports ES6 outside custom templates (and even there only a subset, such as let/const and arrow functions). I will amend the answer accordingly.